Issue with Initializing DataTable in Angular 18 using `simple-datatables` and `Tailwind CSS`
I am trying to implement a data table using the simple-datatables library in an Angular 18 project. The table is styled with Tailwind CSS, and I have multiple interactive features such as searching and pagination. However, I am encountering an issue where the data table does not initialize correctly, or the table loses functionality when trying to reinitialize after data updates.
I have implemented the table within my component template and used Tailwind CSS for styling. The data is being fetched and displayed properly, but the DataTable object from the simple-datatables library seems to cause issues with reinitialization.
Details:
I am trying to build a table for managing active users, with features such as sorting, searching, and paginating data. Here’s the relevant code:
HTML Template:
<table id="active-user-table" class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
  <thead class="bg-gray-100">
    <tr>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Sr</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Name</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Username</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Email</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Role</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Active</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Status</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Created On</th>
      <th class="p-4 text-left text-gray-700 font-medium">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <tr *ngIf="users.length === 0">
      <td colspan="100%" class="p-4 text-center text-gray-500">No active users found.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ i + 1 }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.userName }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td class="p-4">
        <span [ngClass]="getRoleClass(user.roleId)">
          {{ getRoleName(user.roleId) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.isLocked ? 'Locked' : 'Unlocked' }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 text-gray-600">{{ user.createdOn }}</td>
      <td class="p-4 flex">
        <button
              class="bg-amber-500 text-white text-xs p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-amber-700"
              title="{{ user.isLocked ? 'Unlock User' : 'Lock User' }}"
              (click)="toggleLock(user.id)"
            >
              <i class="fa-solid fa-key"></i>
            </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Component TypeScript:
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable } from 'simple-datatables';
import { ActiveUsersService } from './services/active-users.service';
import { LoaderService } from '../../../../shared/services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-users',
  templateUrl: './active-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-users.component.css'],
})
export class ActiveUsersComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  users: any[] = [];
  dataTable: DataTable | undefined;

  constructor(private activeUsersService: ActiveUsersService, private loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    this.activeUsersService.getActiveUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data;
      this.initializeDataTable();
    });
  }

  initializeDataTable(): void {
    const tableElement = document.getElementById('active-user-table');
    if (tableElement) {
      if (this.dataTable) {
        this.dataTable.destroy(); // To avoid multiple initializations
      }
      this.dataTable = new DataTable(tableElement as HTMLTableElement, {
        searchable: true,
        perPage: 10,
      });
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initializeDataTable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.dataTable) {
      this.dataTable.destroy();
    }
  }

  toggleLock(userId: number) {
    this.message = 'Do you want to lock/unlock this user?';
    this.userIdToLockUnlock = userId;
    this.showLockunlockConfirmationDialog = true;
  }
}

Problem:
Reinitialization Issue:
The table doesn't properly reinitialize when new data is fetched.
Losing DataTable Functionality:
When updating the data or navigating between pages, the DataTable library seems to lose its sorting, searching, or pagination functionality.
What I've Tried:
Using DataTable.destroy() to remove the instance before reinitializing.
Confirming that the table element is correctly rendered in the DOM before calling new DataTable().
Expected Outcome:
The data table should initialize with full functionality (sorting, searching, pagination), and should reinitialize cleanly after data updates.
